# Raspberry pi power up button and i2c devices

Tags: pi-3, i2c

I have a ads1115 connected to my i2c pins of the raspberry pi. The i2c pins are pin 2 (i2c-SDA) and pin 3 (i2c-scl).

Additionally i want to power up and shutdown my pi with the WAKE_ON_GPIO. [Example](https://howchoo.com/g/mwnlytk3zmm/how-to-add-a-power-button-to-your-raspberry-pi). WAKE_ON_GPIO is only available on pin 3.

I now added the cable for the button as well as the scl-cable of my ads1115 to pin 3. Unfortunately the i2c is not working anymore after this.

[image: Circuit Layout]

When using `i2cdetect -y 1` it takes approximately 1-3s for each address. And i am not finding my i2c devices anymore. The Boot Up and down is working perfectly.

Comment: If you actually did this it will work. Post diagnostics.

Comment: Added the ```i2cdetect -y 1``` diagnostic. But i am not sure how i can do some more diagnostic besides that. Any Tipps for this are welcome

Comment: What you posted is not a diagnostic - it is your interpretation. There is NO WAY connecting a button (which is just 2 wires if not pressed) can change this, so obviously you DO NOT have what you posted. Your question implies AFTER you did something it doesn't work - post BEFORE & AFTER and show wiring. DO NOT post Comments - EDIT your question.